# How to get few last rows from related table?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

Need help with a `orm` request.

There are 2 tables. `Author` and `Book` (names for example, so you don't need to look at the logic), linked through `FK`.

```
class Book(models.Models):
  title = models.Charfield(...)
  
  
class Author(models.Model):
  book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

Need to group the authors by the book and go through them in a loop. The question is how to select only the *last 50 authors of each book*.

I can write this:

```
for book in Book.all()
    for author in  book.author_set.all()[:50]:
        ....
```

But this is not an optimal solution.

Comment: Why is that not optimal? What is the solution you're looking for?

Comment: A book with more than 50 authors?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes. Name of `tables` I wrote for example. If you want, can change `Author` to `BookInstance`...

Comment: @Vincent I don't want to make query to database in each *book* iteration...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I need this on `django orm` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-top-n-group.html

Answer (score -1):

Bad answer, I didn't realize that slicing implies a new query.  My bad, don't look further down.

To optimize your query, you need to use the prefetch_related() method:

> prefetch_related()
> Returns a QuerySet
> that will automatically retrieve, in a single batch, related objects
> for each of the specified lookups.
>
> This has a similar purpose to select_related, in that both are
> designed to stop the deluge of database queries that is caused by
> accessing related objects, but the strategy is quite different.
>
> select_related works by creating an SQL join and including the fields
> of the related object in the SELECT statement. For this reason,
> select_related gets the related objects in the same database query.
> However, to avoid the much larger result set that would result from
> joining across a ‘many’ relationship, select_related is limited to
> single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one.
>
> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each
> relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to
> prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done
> using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one
> relationships that are supported by select_related.

```
for book in Book.all().prefetch_related()
    for author in  book.author_set.all()[:50]
```

You also need to order your book.author_set queryset to make sure you get the latest entries.

Comment: Wouldn't there be a query on every iteration of the book in this case?

Comment: `prefetch_related` is not going to help any here, that slice `[:50]` implies a _new_ query, hence in fact all that prefetching is going to be wasteful.

Comment: http://www.silota.com/docs/recipes/sql-top-n-group.html